# Openssl - SHA256 (Base-64) using command line

Tags: openssl

I have to add hash total of a string to a file. Hash total is SHA-256 (Base-64).

String stream would be as below:

```
 Transaction Type|External System Reference Number|Original External System Reference|Account title|SAP Company Number|Payment Currency|Payment Amount|Trade / Posting Date|Settlement Date|Client Account (SAP)|Client Number (SAP)|Benficiarys bank sort code|Beneficiarys bank swift code|Beneficiarys Bank Line 1|Beneficiarys Bank Line 2|Intermediary Bank|Intermediary swift code|FX Rate|Beneficiary Customer|Beneficiary Account Number|Beneficiary’s Bank Country|Resereved for future use|Creation Date / Time|Payment Details|Bank to Bank Info|Payment Charges|Ordering Customer|File Origination Code|Resereved for future use|Charge account|Resereved for future use|Resereved for future use|Resereved for future use
FCYOut|TESTREF000101||A Company Limited|GB0010001|EUR|0000000663.75|20130327|20130402|10000001|90023562||SBZAZAJJXXX|Standard Bank Joburg|Sandton Joburg||||John Smith|1010102356|ZA||20130327163043|Invoice 23B|Branch code 234234|SHA||XXXX|||||
```

When i do hash total with below command

```
echo -n $txt | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 | openssl base64
```

it gives value as below:

```
SqL7nAwQ/Y+2LXXfLaX25CtfSjoShY9+FCRZp5jcGO0=
```

But when i send it to the other party they are getting wrong information after decrypt:

They are expecting below encrypted string for the above sample message

```
1EjGezzIXFT+/QvXUuK1juo8rUJGuymRmUnXgA8OzA8=
```

Can anyone please help me what is wrong here ? I want value to be same as the other party output.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding is `UTF8` and there is no line delimiter. Here's the C# code I use to test:

```
SHA256 sha = new SHA256Managed();
StringBuilder sbTest = new StringBuilder();
sbTest.Append("Transaction Type|External System Reference Number|Original External System Reference|Account title|SAP Company Number|Payment Currency|Payment Amount|Trade / Posting Date|Settlement Date|Client Account (SAP)|Client Number (SAP)|Benficiarys bank sort code|Beneficiarys bank swift code|Beneficiarys Bank Line 1|Beneficiarys Bank Line 2|Intermediary Bank|Intermediary swift code|FX Rate|Beneficiary Customer|Beneficiary Account Number|Beneficiary’s Bank Country|Resereved for future use|Creation Date / Time|Payment Details|Bank to Bank Info|Payment Charges|Ordering Customer|File Origination Code|Resereved for future use|Charge account|Resereved for future use|Resereved for future use|Resereved for future use");
sbTest.Append("FCYOut|TESTREF000101||A Company Limited|GB0010001|EUR|0000000663.75|20130327|20130402|10000001|90023562||SBZAZAJJXXX|Standard Bank Joburg|Sandton Joburg||||John Smith|1010102356|ZA||20130327163043|Invoice 23B|Branch code 234234|SHA||XXXX|||||");

string str = sbTest.ToString();
byte[] data = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));
StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
}

string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
Console.WriteLine(base64String);
```